# What are the X symbols in a board layout file?

Tags: eda

I'm viewing a board layout file in Mentor PADS and there are X symbols all over the board. I'm not sure what they indicate, but they don't seem to be a part of any layer and I can't hide them. I'd at least like to know what they are, but also knowing how to disable them in this viewer would be helpful as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The X indicates an **airwire of zero length**

Try activating route and clicking on it and moving it, then shift+left-click to place via.

Comment: Are these airwires just the result of direct connections to a GND or PWR plane?

I'm only using the free viewer, so I can't move anything. I don't see a ROUTE option.

Comment: (edited) There are several different reasons that could cause it. Try **F9** or you should be able to find route in the Tool menu. Can you scroll on the top menu, tool->auto->general tab->Load->ee_autoroute.ctl? (might need to download ee_autoroute.ctl)

Answer (score 0):

When I use PADS, they generally indicate where you have vias or pads connected to net layers. They indicate where via connections will be made and thermal spokes will be generated.

edit: When copper is poured, it will be the location of a plane connection.